# replacing variables inside an If statement

Tags: function-construction, functional-style

```
ClearAll[x, xx, z]
xx = Array[x, 2];
y = If[z == 0, 0, xx[[2]]]
```

gives for y:

`If[z == 0, 0, xx[[2]]]`

I want to see

`If[z == 0, 0, x[2]]`

I can't figure out how to do this. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

You can wrap the third argument of `If` with `Evaluate` to force evaluation of that expression:

```
y = If[z == 0, 0, Evaluate@xx[[2]]]
```

> If[z == 0, 0, x[2]]

[`If >> Details`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/If.html):

> ***If[condition,t,f]* is left unevaluated if *condition* evaluates to neither *True* nor *False*.**

For example:

```
w = 3;
If[z == 0, 2 w, w^2]
```

> If[z == 0, 2 w, w^2]

whereas

```
If[True, 2 w, w^2]
```

> 6

```
If[False, 2 w, w^2]
```

> 9

Since `If` has the attibute [`HoldRest`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/HoldRest.html) the second and third arguments remain unevaluated until the first argument is determined to be `True` or `False`(in the former case only the second argument is evaluated and in the latter only the third argument). So, when the first argument evaluates to `False` you do get `x[2]` as the output from `If` without the need to wrap the third argument with `Evaluate`:

```
If[False, 0, xx[[2]]]
```

> x[2]