# Evaluate all If branches

Tags: evaluation

In Mathematica, I have the following code:

```
f1[x_] := 1;
f2[x_] := 2;
f[x_] := If[x > 5, f1[x], If[x < 0, f2[x], 3]]

f[x]
```

Which produces the following output:

```
If[x > 5, f1[x], If[x < 0, f2[x], 3]]
```

How can I get this output:

```
If[x > 5, 1, If[x < 0, 2, 3]]
```

Comment: try ``ClearAll[f]; f[x_] := Internal`InheritedBlock[{If}, ClearAttributes[If, HoldRest]; 
  If[x > 5, f1[x], If[x < 0, f2[x], 3]]]``?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Arguments to If\[\] are not evaluated](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3394/arguments-to-if-are-not-evaluated) Also: [replacing variables inside an If statement](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/212329/replacing-variables-inside-an-if-statement)

Comment: Try: `f[x_] :=  With[{t1 = f1[x], t2 = f2[x]}, If[x > 5, t1, If[x < 0, t2, 3]]]`

Comment: try also `ClearAll[f]; f[x_] := If[x > 5, #, If[x < 0, #2, 3]] &[f1[x], f2[x]]`